# Unable to compile .c file in Visual Studio code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang

I have created a file in Visual Studio code titled mario.c with the following

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("????\n");
}
```

In terminal when I input

```
make mario
```

I get the following error

```
make mario
cc     mario.c   -o mario
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

I'm a beginner and not sure why I am getting this error.

I have clang installed (done through brew) and c/c++ extension in Visual Studio code. Not sure what else to do

I was hoping to compile the c file so I could ./mario and run printf

Comment: You're mixing an x86-targeting compiler with an arm-targeting binary toolchain

Comment: You should learn about how the compiler chain works, GCC is a good starting point because there is a lot of resources on it. http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/fall14/cs143/project/cpp/gcc-intro.html

Comment: If you are a Windows system, you can try visual studio or MingW64 tools to compile your code. If you are a Linux system, you should try GCC or Clang.You should try compiling it manually. `gcc mario.c -Wall -o mario.exe`